# Is there a command to see what access rights you have for a repo?

Tags: git, github, read-write

How can I tell what read/write access rights I have on a repo? Someone else made me a branch so that I can change things and submit for his approval, but I keep getting the error:

```
fatal: {my-repo-name} does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

When I run git fetch --all:

> "Fetching origin remote: Enumerating objects: 458, done. remote:
> Counting objects: 100% (458/458), done. remote: Compressing objects:
> 100% (153/153), done. remote: Total 358 (delta 244), reused 289 (delta
> 178), pack-reused 0 Receiving objects: 100% (358/358), 178.64 KiB |
> 6.38 MiB/s, done. Resolving deltas: 100% (244/244), completed with 69 local objects. From github.com/{the-rest-of-the-url}
>
> 8e8c257..e60d27f dev -> origin/dev  f1fc1ae..e60d27f main ->
> origin/main"

I believe the issue may be that I only have read rights.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "Someone else made me a branch" - a branch? or a fork? In `git`-proper (not GitHub, etc) branches cannot have access-controls, only in remotely-hosted repos (like GitHub, GitLab, TFS, Azure DevOps, etc) can [pushes to branches be blocked](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/about-protected-branches) by access-controls.

Comment: That error message sounds like you're just using the wrong repo URI. **Exactly what** was the full command-line were you using? Please don't obfuscate the entire URI, only mask sensitive substrings.

Comment: They walked me through cloning the files to my computer and they made me a branch so that me and my colleague can submit changes. I only want to push the changes up to that branch for his review.

Comment: Dai, he had me clone using the clone button and then the "HTTPS" url

Comment: Well.... if you had read-only rights, then it makes sense that you can't push. Can you run `git fetch --all`?

Comment: eftshift, what does that command do? I just don't want to mess anything up with the site. Thanks!

Comment: @eftshift0 (and @jane doe): `git fetch --all` means *fetch from all remotes*. If you only have one remote (`origin`), it does exactly the same thing as `git fetch`.

Comment: all it does is take a peek at the remote and refresh the information you have about it on your local repo. Nothing will be pushed, nothing will be pulled. If it fails with the same kind of message, then i would not think it's a permissions problem but rather having to make sure you have the right URL for the repo.

Comment: Thank you @eftshift0 . I ran the command and it came back...

"Fetching origin
remote: Enumerating objects: 458, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (458/458), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (153/153), done.
remote: Total 358 (delta 244), reused 289 (delta 178), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (358/358), 178.64 KiB | 6.38 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (244/244), completed with 69 local objects.
From https://github.com/{the-rest-of-the-url}
   8e8c257..e60d27f  dev        -> origin/dev
   f1fc1ae..e60d27f  main       -> origin/main

Comment: I guess that you could add that to the original question.... and we can be certain that the URL is not the problem. Looks like a permissions problem.

Comment: @eftshift0 Ok. Thank you!

Comment: Is there some command I can type in to check my read/ write access?

Comment: @torek it's ok. It was not an oversight on my part. The question didn't specify anything about the remote (or remotes) the OP has set up so just asking to run with `-a` makes sure we don't miss the info we are after.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there some command I can type in to check my read/ write access

No. The way you know you have read access it that you can read. The way you know you don't have write access is that you cannot write.

In GitHub, if you see Settings for this repo (rightmost link across the top of the screen), you can view the access rights for the repo. But you probably don't see it because this is not your repo.

You would need the owner of the repo to double-check this for you.